# Wordpress: adding active class to wp_nav_menu items

Tags: css, wordpress

In Wordpress (3.0.1), if I use the GUI to update the Main Menu to include an item called News:

**

```
URL: /news/
Navigation Label: News
Title Attribute: news
```

**

the News item shows up in my menu. Great. But when I click on it and navigate to the /news/ page, WordPress does not add a current_menu_item class to the `<li>`.

Nor does it give the `<li>` menu item an id or a name of "news" - instead it's called something unhelpful like "menu-item-899".

Why doesn't WordPress just add the current_menu_item class? Surely it has all the information it needs to do this? `</grumble>`

And given the above, how can I style the `<li>` item to show that it is the current item? I really don't want to have to use jquery to look at the page name and match it to arbitrarily-named ids... is that my only option?

Answer (score 1):

You could use this CSS Style :

```
/*.current-menu-item controls active state on nav menu */
#primary-menu ul li.current-menu-item a, ul li ul li.current-menu-item a {
 color:#663;

 }
```